# Help! Ubuntu 20.04 Server is printing kernel messages to my console

Tags: kernel, syslog, logging

after setting up a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 server, exactly every 5 minutes and 11 seconds my console shows the following message, which is printed above everything on the screen:

```
Message from syslogd@haven1 at May  8 22:28:19 ...
 kernel:[  627.813546] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.

Message from syslogd@haven1 at May  8 22:28:19 ...
 kernel:[  627.813565] [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (10:6:3) MC2_STATUS[Over|CE|-|AddrV|-]: 0xd400000000000011

Message from syslogd@haven1 at May  8 22:28:19 ...
 kernel:[  627.813577] [Hardware Error]: Error Addr: 0x0000000098a0eff8

Message from syslogd@haven1 at May  8 22:28:19 ...
 kernel:[  627.813583] [Hardware Error]: MC2 Error: INSN error in a Page Descriptor Cache or Guest TLB.

Message from syslogd@haven1 at May  8 22:28:19 ...
 kernel:[  627.813593] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: INSN
```

Seems to be a problem with the cache. But, however, this error message is not new, I know them for quite a long time and the server runs stable. But after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 server, the message prints on my ssh console, so its quite annoying to work with it.

so far I tried the following to get this silent:

`sudo dmesg -n 1`

`sudo dmesg -D`

changing the loglevel in /etc/sysctl.conf to:

`kernel.printk 1 4 1 3`

I even stopped the rsyslog service

nothing made a change, still seeing this messages...

I think there is a setting to stop it, as with previously running Ubuntu 16.04 server the message only appeared in syslog, not on console.

Any idea welcome.

Comment: **Better to fix the hardware error, than trying to hide/ignore the error messages**. Probably a memory problem. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people *want* to know about messages like this because they point to serious issues that the OS is contending with. Hopefully this server is not being used for any mission-critical purposes ….

That said, if you insist on hiding these messages to the console, then you’ll need to set a different virtual console in the Grub configuration and reboot (because the virtual console cannot be changed dynamically).

Here’s how:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Edit the Grub configuration file in a text editor of your choice:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`
3. Add/Edit the `console` setting:

   ```
   console=ttyS0
   ```
4. Save and close the file
5. Update the Grub configuration

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot the machine

This will do what you’re looking for. To undo it in the future, remove the `console` setting, update Grub, and reboot.

Comment: Much better to fix the real problem, than to hide the error messages.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Nothing crtitical on that server, its just a 8 year old NAS for my music and videos, so as long as it runs, I'll not buy new hardware ;)

later i figured out that uncommenting

Comment: later i figured out that uncommenting

*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*


in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf 

also stops kernel messages from beeing printed to console

Comment: This is exactly the kind of problem you **don't** want to know about, because there's nothing you can do to fix it. It runs for as long as it runs. You need backups anyway. YOLO.